# How to enable users belonging to group sonar-users see the analysis of the project done by the sonar-administrator?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I have a community edition of sonarqube (version 8.8) setup running on GKE. I have created a public project using the Administrator user and running a jenkins job for python code analysis. Below is my sonarqube-scanner properties in Jenkins job:

```
sonar.projectKey=ws-python
sonar.scm.disabled = True
sonar.sources=./$branch/${BUILD_NUMBER}/backend/
sonar.language=py
sonar.host.url=http://<ip-address-of-sonarqube>
sonar.login=<project-key>
```

I created few users which by default belongs to **sonar-users** group and provided them the below access:

[image]

Upon successful analysis of the code, as an administrator user, I am able to see the dashboard with all the issues like bugs, vulnerabilities , security hotspots etc. But when I am seeing the same dashboard as any users belonging to the group **sonar-users**, I am unable to see anything in the dashboard. And I am getting below error:

[image]

Also, I have provided the access to all the users of the group **sonar-users** for the project.
Can anyone help me how I can make these projects accessible to all the users?

Comment: Are the users that you have given access belongs to any LDAP or AD group ?

Comment: No, I have created it manually from the UI.

Comment: Can you try once by giving the permission to users individually.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but it is not working. I even tried to give all the possible access.